# Intel Rapid Storage RAID 5 error, "Missing Drive"

Tags: motherboard, raid, raid-5, intel-rst

Just recently I purchased a new motherboard for my PC due to the fact I had a motherboard with the defective 67 Intel chipset. The reason I bought the new motherboard was because I started getting drive failure reports on all the drives and I made the assumption that it was due to the SATA ports "degrading".

After installing the new motherboard and reinstalling windows on my 500gig drive, I wanted to get my RAID5 array working (3x 2TB Western Digital Greens). Unfortunately, only one of the drives is being recognized as a RAID drive as part of the RAID array. The other two are being considered Non-RAID disks.

The Intel Rapid Storage application can see the RAID array but only sees one of the three disks, the other two disk are still in the "Storage System View", but not in the RAID array.

My system specs are:

> Intel core i7 2600
>   Gigabyte GA-Z68A-D3-B3 ([Specs](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3863#sp))
>   8gb Corsair RAM
>   NVidia GeForce GTX580
>   1x 500gig HDD
>   3x 2TB Western Digital Green

I'm wondering how I would be able to add the drives back to the array. I did back up the most important stuff on the array to an external drive, but there is still a lot on there that I would prefer to get back.

Also, the previous motherboard I used was an ASRock H67M-GE ([Specs](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=H67M-GE&cat=Specifications)).

Comment: Screenshot of intel rapid storage app: [link](http://i51.tinypic.com/3t2lc.jpg)

Comment: Purchased?  Why didn't you just get an RMA for one with the fixed B3 revision chipset...?  (I will say that those errors WERE probably chipset failures, I've seen it happen at least once on these.)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the mix of sata 6gb and sata 3gb you must have multiple sata controllers on your motherboard.  It's possible you have some drives on one controller and some on the other probably non intel controller.  Hopefully the one with four sockets is the intel controller but I couldn't find any information on the page you linked to.

Comment: I didn't think that would be an issue as the 500gig drive showed up in the RAID configuration (And that drive is on a 6gb port while the others are on 3). Just to be absolutely sure, I plugged all my RAID drives into the 6gb ports (with one in a 3gb port) hoping that at least 2 drives will show up in the RAID array. But nope, didn't work.

Comment: Umm, i'm not sure about the intel raid software but it's possible that it's looking for each drive to be in a particular socket to it might be worth trying one of the unrecognised drives in each of the available sockets and seeing if it turns up in the array.

Comment: I've tried swapping around the ports on all the non-RAID disks (that should be RAID), I haven't been able to get any of them to show up as part of the RAID array that way.